# Deallocating BufferGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

As the basis for my scene objects, I have a single root Object3D. My data is loaded as a tree structure of Object3Ds from this root. Meshes are added to the leaf Object3Ds, using BufferGeometry/MeshPhongMaterial. I clear the existing tree by passing the root Object3D into this method:

```
clearScene:
    function (obj) {
        if (obj instanceof THREE.Mesh)
        {
            obj.geometry.dispose();
            obj.geometry = undefined;
            obj.material.dispose();
            obj.material = undefined;
            obj = undefined;
        }
        else
        {
            if (obj.children !== undefined) {
                while (obj.children.length > 0) {
                    this.clearScene(obj.children[0]); // removing children changes the length of the array.
                    obj.remove(obj.children[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Consider the following simple tree:

- Scene (Scene)

  - Root (Object3D)

    - Branch (Object3D)

      - Leaf (Mesh)

Once this structure is in the scene, I observe the heap (using Chrome's dev tools). I can see 3 Object3Ds objects, and 2 Mesh objects (the extras are the prototypes).

When I call clearScene(Root), I see it step through the tree, removing the Object3Ds, and cleaning up the meshes.  But when I observe the heap, I see that although the Object3Ds have been removed, the 2 Mesh objects (and their associated BufferGoemetry and Material objects) remain. If I load the data a second time after clearing, I see 3 Object3Ds (okay), and 4 Meshes (not okay).

I believe this means that a reference isn't getting cleared correctly, but I didn't see any retainers in the heap that would do this.

I must be missing something else which is causing these objects to hang around.

r69dev (<strike>I was seeing the same in r68</strike>), testing in Chrome 36.0.1985.125

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: You can see my jsfiddle for it here (http://jsfiddle.net/TheJim01/mw9Df/51/), but that demo is working mostly as expected--it does completely remove the Mesh and Material objects, so my code must be hanging onto the Mesh object somewhere else. That said, the above fiddle _doesn't_ fully remove the BufferGeometry object, but that may be because of how I defined it.

Comment: I was doing more testing today, and I must have jumbled my versions. r68 **does** clear memory correctly, but r69dev **does not**. I'll try to trace it back to a root cause, and submit a bug, if it hasn't already been addressed/fixed.

Comment: Oh! It'll be great if you can find the culprit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue (concern) submitted on github: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5175

r69dev requires an explicit call to the dispose method for meshes to properly remove references held by the renderer.

Working code:

```
clearScene:
function (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {
        obj.geometry.dispose();
        obj.geometry = null;
        obj.material.dispose();
        obj.material = null;
        obj.dispose(); // required in r69dev to remove references from the renderer.
        obj = null;
    }
    else
    {
        if (obj.children !== undefined) {
            while (obj.children.length > 0) {
                this.clearScene(obj.children[0]);
                obj.remove(obj.children[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```